# How do I plot benchmark data in a Jenkins matrix project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have several Jenkins matrix projects in where I output benchmark results (i.e. execution times) in a CSV file. I'd like to plot these execution times as a function of the build number, so I can see if my projects are regressing over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm [Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) is a correct and quite useful approach. BTW, it supports CSV as well: [plot configuration example](http://tiernok.com/LTDBlog/ContinuousDelivery/LoadTest_Config8.png)

[image]

I've been using it for several years without any problem. Benchmarks results were generated as a property file. Benchmark id (series id) was used as a key and result as a value. One build produces one result for each benchmark. Having that data it is quite easy to create plot configuration ant track performance.

Comment: Just to precise, you can find a sample CSV files on the project [github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plot-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/test.csv)

Answer (score 2):

This may help you:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin

It adds plotting capabilities to Jenkins.