# Jenkins - How to get difference between two runs

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Whenever there is a change in tests we are triggering a Jenkin's Job
For example: Add/Remove few testcases and Run the Job
I need to see how many tests have been added and removed when compared to prev run.
Also I need to compare Run1 details with RunX details.

Please let me know if we can do these in Jenkins? Is there any plugins for the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to compare just build artifacts, or also contents of workspace (which normally get overwritten)?

Comment: only build artifacts. Example: Build1- Contains 30 tests , Build2-Added 10 tests. A graph to show the differeces. (like a dashboard to generate chats etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can echo number of available tests and use [Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) to visualize the dynamics. Please see another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12780819/1435741):

Please note, default test result trend does the job for me (it shows total number of tests).

[image]
[image]