# How to test performance of java DBMS application

Tags: java, database, junit, jenkins, performance-testing

Here is my scenario:

I have a java application that reads data from a table T1 of database D1, processes it and puts it in another table T2 of another database D2. This happens real time, i.e., as and when a record is inserted or updated in table T1, the application will pick the data, process it and pushes it to the destination table. I wish to monitor performance of this application using a testing(preferrably JUnit) and/or performance framework. In my test case I wish to have following

- Insert and update a fixed number of records for fixed time at fixed intervals on table T1 of database D1.
- After a fixed time, either check the number of records that are present in T2 of database D2 or look for existence of a specific record.

The tests that I wish to create should be

- Database agnostic
- Provide results that can show trends and be configurable with a CI tool like Jenkins

So, my question is, what is the best way to test this kind of scenario? Are there any available tools that will help me achieve this?

Comment: This is not a real-time application, unless it runs on a real-time version of Java, running on a real-time operation system. Don't misuse standard CS terminology.

Comment: @EJP: I am not very sure of what you meant, but I was under the impression that a real-time application is one which is bound by time constraints. The data has to be moved from one DB to another in real time. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: @ShivaKumar, dose you DB guarantee a response within strict time constraints? Do you think it is possible to build a real-time system on the top of any solution?

Comment: @RenatGilmanov: It is a valid point that you have made. But we have got dedicated test servers in a controlled environment. We do not expect any discrepancies to creep into the system. Our results could vary marginally in each rum but they should lie in an established interval. Any drastic variations in the performance is what we will be more interested in.

Answer (score 1):

**Database agnostic**

In order to achieve that I would suggest to use simplest possible SQL and some low-level JDBC abstraction layer:

[DBUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/)

> The Commons DbUtils library is a small set of classes designed to make
>   working with JDBC easier. JDBC resource cleanup code is mundane, error
>   prone work so these classes abstract out all of the cleanup tasks from
>   your code leaving you with what you really wanted to do with JDBC in
>   the first place: query and update data.

[MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/core/)

> MyBatis is a first class persistence framework with support for custom
>   SQL, stored procedures and advanced mappings. MyBatis eliminates
>   almost all of the JDBC code and manual setting of parameters and
>   retrieval of results. MyBatis can use simple XML or Annotations for
>   configuration and map primitives, Map interfaces and Java POJOs (Plain
>   Old Java Objects) to database records.

Both will do the trick for you. With good attention to details you'll manage to provide flexible enough solution and test as many databases as you want.

**Provide results that can show trends and be configurable with a CI tool like Jenkins**

Define several [KPIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_performance_indicator) and make sure you can get all values periodically. For example you can measure a throughput (records per second). Export data periodically (as CSV or properties for example) and use [PlotPlugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) for visualization:

[image]

You can also check relevant question: [How do I plot benchmark data in a Jenkins matrix project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12719194/1435741)

**Proper testing**

Please make sure your testing strategy is well defined and you will not miss anything:

1. [Load testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing)
2. [Stress testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing)