# C++ Performance Metrics Integrated with Jenkins

Tags: c++, performance, jenkins

I want to run automatic performance tests on C++ programs and run/monitor them within Jenkins. The performance metrics could be based on windows, Linux or Mac OSX. My goal is to be able to compare over a long period of time different version of my programs, see speed improvements ideally with graphs and charts. Any idea?

Comment: I am not really sure what you need. What is a "performance metrics"? Time to execute something (tests?), or some numbers?

Comment: Yes, performance in terms of how long it takes to execute some tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are taking the time to execute some tests as a performance measure, then using [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) to get the execution time may be good enough. There are various times, but CPU time might suit your needs.

The time command has another outputs that you may find useful.

So, what you need to do is to add a jenkins job to execute a bash script. In this script, you will execute the application, and parse the output.

You'll get the output in this format :

```
$ time ll
real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

and you need to process it, and put the value into a file. Then you are going to load the value using the [plot plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin). The plugin is going to do the rest.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12780819/476681) explains how to set the plot plugin, if you prefer to export data in cvs format.

Comment: How could I import the results into Jenkins?

Comment: While jenkins plot plugin seems the way to go, it seems broken as it does not provide a "plot build data" post build actions for existing jobs...

Comment: @Korchkidu No, it doesn't provide, but why can't you add a post build action for the job? What would you do in it? I understood that you want to show some plot

Comment: Well, the idea would be to instrument my C++ code to produce a CSV file with execution time information. Then in Jenkins, with the plot plugin, I could import this information as a chart. I am considering instrumenting the code + generating an HTML report and then importing it into Jenkins myself...

Comment: @Korchkidu If you go that way, I surely hope your application is not going to be blocked by other applications during execution, otherwise your metrics will not be very valuable.

Comment: Well, it is possible to focus on CPU time only, not wall time. Also, to mitigate performance variations, you normally perform a lot a measurements and discards those significantly deviating from the other data points.

Comment: I wonder about the time utility effectivity if the program is multithreaded. I recall that under multithreading, this didn't work correctly. I think it's worth to be warned about this fact, because it showed the sum of all threads execution `real`time instead of the real time the program took to execute, distorting results.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it made me realize that I will have to do it basically "manually" with the HTMLPublisher plugin;) Thanks!